# How to exec two commands in one find

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix, find

I would like to

1. find specific folders
2. echo their name
3. ls -l their contents

My problem is that I don't know how to combine an `echo {}` and an `ls -l {}` in one find command.

line for echo:

`sudo find / -type d -name 'yt' -exec echo {} \;`

line for ls:

`sudo find / -type d -name 'yt' -exec ls -l {} \;`

How can I combine these two?

note: I prefer not to use xargs if possible, as it has problems with escaping filenames properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just put two different `-exec` options in the same `find` command?

This works for me:

```
$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
```

```
$ find . -type d -name mydir -exec echo {} \; -exec ls -l {} \;
./mydir
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 daniel daniel 0 févr. 25 15:32 myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not generic solution but will work for you since you search for directories:

> sudo find / -type d -name 'yt' -execdir readlink -f {} \; -exec ls -l {} \;

The execdir executes a command on the subdirectory matching the found file (which, since you search for the directories) is the directory itself (and readlink -f gives it's full path). The second -exec will on the other side match the directory again and do the "ls -" on them.

Using jsut echo on the first execdir wouldn't write you the full path but just the last directory which may not be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the print command here easily.

```
$sudo find / -type d -name 'bin' -print  -exec ls -l {} \;
```

For example,

1. find bin folders
2. echo their name  or print their names
3. ls -l their contents - list their contents.